# Where is stored when I use console.log() on Google Actions?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to log to help to debug my code using console.log() on Google Actions using webhook. But I can't find it anywhere.
Where is stored the output console.log()?

```
console.log('')
```

I tried to find in Stackdriver log, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stored in Stackdriver if you're using Cloud Functions on Google Cloud or Firebase. Make sure that you adjust the filter to logs from *Cloud Function*

[image]

If you're not using Google Cloud for hosting your webhook, you'll need to check your hosting provider.